# What DataSet does this code use? The documentation for SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) makes them sound mandatory

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, ado.net, sqldataadapter

The following code is adapted from [Microsoft's code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/modifying-data-with-stored-procedures#example). It is therefore obviously correct.

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        ReturnIdentity(connectionString);
    }

    private static void ReturnIdentity(string connectionString)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // Create a SqlDataAdapter based on a SELECT query.
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories", connection);

            // Create a DataTable and fill it.
            DataTable categories = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(categories);
        }
    }

    static private string GetConnectionString()
    {
       return "Your Connection String";
    }  
}
```

Despite this obviously correct code containing no `DataSet` that I can find, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable)) for the `Fill` method called with `adapter.Fill(categories)` above makes repeated mentions of `DataSet`s, as if they're somehow relevant/mandatory to using the `Fill(DataTable)` method of the `SqlDataAdapter` class.

This gives me my question: Where in the above code does any `DataSet` appear? I can't think of any reading of the documentation for `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` that doesn't make it sound like you absolutely need one.

Comment: I think it's poor documentation. They were lazy when they added the overloads for `DataTable` and `DataTable[]`. All are using the same `FillInternal` and even the `DataTable` overloads use the `DataSet` property of `DataTable` to enforce it's constraints. But it's just confusing wording, because you actually fill just the `DataTable`. Btw, the interface `IDataAdapter` just has a [`Fill(DataSet)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0) method, maybe that's why they are so DataSet-focused in the documentation.

Comment: Honestly, the number of times you should be using DataSet/DataTable is ***vanishingly*** small, making this a non-issue. They were mostly a transition API for ADO record-sets. That was a very long time ago.

Comment: @MarcGravell What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: *"It is therefore obviously correct."* probably not to be honest, there is a lot of incorrect or poor docs out there. @MarcGravell is suggesting to use things like Entity Framework or Dapper, which handle resultsets completely differently, directly into object models

Comment: @J.Mini Dapper, EF, something like that

Comment: @MarcGravell Would if I could, but I'm stuck with ADO.NET at the moment. When I'm finally permitted Dapper and EF, I'm sure that this slog will make me respect them even more.

Comment: The documentation for `Adapter.Fill` was always slanted towards using `DataSets`.  When you fill just a `DataTable`, that's all you have.  Don't over think this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will help:

- A [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-7.0) is made up of a collection of tables, relationships, and constraints. In ADO.NET, [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/datatables) objects are used to represent the tables in a DataSet. A DataTable represents one table of in-memory relational data; the data is local to the .NET-based application in which it resides, but can be populated from a data source such as Microsoft SQL Server using a DataAdapter For more information, see [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter).
- The [overload of Fill that takes DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable)) as a parameter only obtains the first result. Use an overload of Fill that takes DataSet as a parameter to obtain multiple results.

So, looking at the code above, the overload is using a DataTable as a parameter, therefore (as per the docs), the the first result in the DataSet will be used.

I think the reference to a DataSet has to do with the SqlDataAdapter - which uses DataSets "under the hood" and the Fill method can accept a DataTable parameter, which is then filled from an underlying DataSet.

Comment: "_the first DataSet within the DataTable will be used._" - I don't believe that DataTables hold DataSets.

Comment: Yes, In ADO.NET, DataTable objects are used to represent the tables IN a DataSet.  The SqlDataAdapter, serves as a bridge between a DataSet and SQL Server for retrieving and saving data. The SqlDataAdapter provides this bridge by mapping Fill, which changes the data in the DataSet to match the data in the data source.   I have updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this in the **Remarks** section:

> The overload of Fill that takes DataTable as a parameter only obtains the first result. Use an overload of Fill that takes DataSet as a parameter to obtain multiple results.

So we see a DataSet is only required if a query batch could have multiple result sets.

Comment: That doesn't tell the reader where a `DataSet` is used. That only explains where you would want to use one.

Answer (score -1):

The SqlDataAdapter class has multiple overloaded versions of Fill that accepts different arguments, including DataSet and DataTable instances. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#methods) for a complete list.

Comment: I tried the same. However, the documentation for `Fill(DataTable)` in the grid that you've linked links to exactly the same place that I did. It therefore has the same problem that I'm discussing. The description on that row even mentions `DataSet`s, so we really are back to square one here.

Comment: A DataSet is made up of a collection of DataTable instances, however you can create a DataTable outside of a dataset, hence the ability to call SqlDataAdapter.Fill with both.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the overload that is clearly specifically for `DataTable`s talks about `DataSet`s.

Comment: @J.Mini: When was the last time the senior person on the team volunteered to write the documentation? Most likely it's a mistake which you should [report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home) so the documentation can be corrected (or clarified).

Comment: @user09938 ADO.NET is more than a decade old now. I struggle to believe it has documentation mistakes.

Comment: @J.Mini: _I struggle to believe it has documentation mistakes_: I don't because people such as yourself fail to report the issue. I'm sure that the people who write the documentation aren't reviewing it for errors every night before going to sleep. Nonetheless, if it's not a mistake, then they'll most likely provide clarification so that you better understand why the documentation says what it says.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. After reading a bit more into the documentation, it seems like the writers were too focused on the fact that a DataTable *can* belong to a DataSet, but doesn't have to.